# How to choose a specific status list Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectedindex

please I have a drop down list like

- creation
- creation from scratch
- creation without data
- creation pay
- modification
- modification/specific
- modification/clean

and this script

```
    function checkTicketType(tipo) {
      console.log("Tipo cambia: "+tipo);
      if (tipo.indexOf('Creation')>-1) {
       $('#itemId').parent().show(500);
      }
      else if (tipo.indexOf('Modification')>-1) {
       $('#itemId').parent().hide(500);
      }

 }
```

When the creation status are selected the itemId box appear, desappear when the modifications are selected. 
My problem I want to use the itemId (it can appear only if the status "modification/specific" is selected no more). 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How I could choose specific word from the list like == "modification specific" in the way to appear the itemId box?

Answer (score 0):

Attach change event to select dropdown. Check for selected text on change event. 
If it contains `modification` hide the `itemId` box (assuming its text input) else if it contains `creation` show it.

```
//Change event for dropdown with id ddForEg
$("#ddForEg").change(function(){

  if($("#ddForEg option:selected").text().includes('modification'))
  {
    alert($("#ddForEg option:selected").text()); 
    $('#itemId').hide(); 
    alert($("#ddForEg").val()); //Another way to see value selected. If you assign value to options. No string operations required in that case. 
   }
  else if($("#ddForEg option:selected").text().includes('creation'))
   {
    $('#itemId').show(); 
   }

 })
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwoavoqd/